# Presenting a Questions and Answers

Tags: beamer

This is a continuation of the topic [Displaying a Numbered Questions and Answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/157260/displaying-a-numbered-questions-and-answer).

I continue to give color to the background, then putting questions and answers in the boxes using [mdframed](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) package.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamercovered{transparent=0}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=lime!20}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{transparent}

\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\mdfdefinestyle{QueFrame}{%
    linecolor       = blue!30,
    outerlinewidth      = 2pt,
    roundcorner     = 10pt,
    leftmargin      = 10pt,
    rightmargin     = 80pt,
    innertopmargin      = \baselineskip,
    innerbottommargin   = \baselineskip,
    innerrightmargin    = 20pt,
    innerleftmargin     = 20pt,
    backgroundcolor     = red!20!white
}

\mdfdefinestyle{AnsFrame}{
    linecolor       = red!30,
    outerlinewidth      = 2pt,
    roundcorner     = 10pt,
    leftmargin      = 80pt,
    rightmargin     = 10pt,
    innertopmargin      = \baselineskip,
    innerbottommargin   = \baselineskip,
    innerrightmargin    = 20pt,
    innerleftmargin     = 20pt,
    backgroundcolor     = blue!20!white
}

\newcounter{num}
\setcounter{num}{0}

\newcommand<>\Que[1]{
    \leavevmode\par
    \stepcounter{num}
    \noindent
    \begin{mdframed}[style=QueFrame]    
        \hbox{          
        {\color{blue}\transparent{0.3}\Huge Q{\huge\thenum}} --- #1}
    \end{mdframed} 
}

\newcommand<>\Ans[2][]{
    \leavevmode\par
    \noindent
    \begin{flushright}
        \begin{mdframed}[style=AnsFrame]
            \textbf{#1} #2  --- {\Huge\color{blue}\transparent{0.3} A}
        \end{mdframed}
    \end{flushright}
}

\resetcounteronoverlays{num}

\begin{mdframed}[style=QueFrame]
    \inserttitle{\huge\color{blue} Questions and Answer}
\end{mdframed}

\begin{mdframed}[style=AnsFrame]
    \insertauthor{\Large\color{blue} Edy Wihardjo}
\end{mdframed}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}

\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=green!20}

\begin{frame}
    \Que{What is \LaTeX{}?}
    \pause
    \Ans{\LaTeX{} is a document preparation system and document markup language!}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \Que{Why I should use \LaTeX?}
    \pause
    \Ans{\LaTeX{} provides very high quality. \LaTeX{} is free and Open Source!}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

**First Problem**

How to set the title to be in the middle of the page?

I've added a command:

```
\begin{frame}
    \vspace{15pt}
    \titlepage
\end{frame}
```

but does not work.

**Second Problem**

[image: FirstQue]

Before displaying the answer, there is an empty text box.

[image: FirstQueAns]

Comment: Which title are you referring about in the first question?

Comment: I mean, title and author on the title page. I can't put it in the middle vertically.

Answer (score 9):

For the first problem, I redefined the `title page` template, to have only title and author. For the second problem. you can use `\only` instead of `\pause`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamercovered{transparent=0}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=lime!20}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{transparent}

\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\mdfdefinestyle{QueFrame}{%
    linecolor       = blue!30,
    outerlinewidth      = 2pt,
    roundcorner     = 10pt,
    leftmargin      = 10pt,
    rightmargin     = 80pt,
    innertopmargin      = \baselineskip,
    innerbottommargin   = \baselineskip,
    innerrightmargin    = 20pt,
    innerleftmargin     = 20pt,
    backgroundcolor     = red!20!white
}

\mdfdefinestyle{AnsFrame}{
    linecolor       = red!30,
    outerlinewidth      = 2pt,
    roundcorner     = 10pt,
    leftmargin      = 80pt,
    rightmargin     = 10pt,
    innertopmargin      = \baselineskip,
    innerbottommargin   = \baselineskip,
    innerrightmargin    = 20pt,
    innerleftmargin     = 20pt,
    backgroundcolor     = blue!20!white
}

\newcounter{num}

\newcommand<>\Que[1]{
    \leavevmode\par
    \stepcounter{num}
    \noindent
    \begin{mdframed}[style=QueFrame]    
        \hbox{          
        {\color{blue}\transparent{0.3}\Huge Q{\huge\thenum}} --- #1}
    \end{mdframed} 
}

\newcommand<>\Ans[2][]{
    \leavevmode\par
    \noindent
    \begin{flushright}
        \begin{mdframed}[style=AnsFrame]
            \textbf{#1} #2  --- {\Huge\color{blue}\transparent{0.3} A}
        \end{mdframed}
    \end{flushright}
}

\resetcounteronoverlays{num}

\makeatletter
\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{cendefault}[1][]
{
  \vbox{}
  \vfill
  \begingroup
    \centering
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,#1]{title}
      \usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle\par%
      \ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty%
      \else%
        \vskip0.25em%
        {\usebeamerfont{subtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subtitle}\insertsubtitle\par}%
      \fi%     
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \vskip1em\par
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,#1]{author}
      \usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor
    \end{beamercolorbox}
%    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,#1]{institute}
%      \usebeamerfont{institute}\insertinstitute
%    \end{beamercolorbox}
%    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,#1]{date}
%      \usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate
%    \end{beamercolorbox}\vskip0.5em
%    {\usebeamercolor[fg]{titlegraphic}\inserttitlegraphic\par}
  \endgroup
  \vfill
}
\makeatother

\setbeamertemplate{title page}[cendefault][center]

\title{The title}
\author{The Author}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}

\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=green!20}

\begin{frame}
\begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{.8\textheight}
    \Que{What is \LaTeX{}?}
    \only<2>{\Ans{\LaTeX{} is a document preparation system and document markup language!}}
\end{overlayarea}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{.8\textheight}
    \Que{Why I should use \LaTeX?}
    \pause
     \only<2>{\Ans{\LaTeX{} provides very high quality. \LaTeX{} is free and Open Source!}}
\end{overlayarea}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I enclosed your questions and answers inside an `overlayarea` environment to keep the questions fixed and preventing from jumping upwards when the answers are presented.

Comment: The second problem has been solved. How to solve the first problem, @Gonzalo Medina?

Comment: I mean, title and author on the title page. I can't put it in the middle vertically.

Comment: @EdyJo please see my updated answer. I assumed you only want to show the author and the title in the title page.

Answer (score 7):

The problem lies in the definitions of `\Que` and `\Ans`:

```
\newcommand<>\Que[1]{
    \leavevmode\par
    \stepcounter{num}
    \noindent
    \begin{mdframed}[style=QueFrame]    
        \hbox{          
        {\color{blue}\transparent{0.3}\Huge Q{\huge\thenum}} --- #1}
    \end{mdframed} 
}

\newcommand<>\Ans[2][]{
    \leavevmode\par
    \noindent
    \begin{flushright}
        \begin{mdframed}[style=AnsFrame]
            \textbf{#1} #2  --- {\Huge\color{blue}\transparent{0.3} A}
        \end{mdframed}
    \end{flushright}
}
```

You are defining overlay-aware commands without explicit use of the overlay specifications. Changing the definitions into:

```
\newcommand<>\Que[1]{
    \leavevmode\par
    \stepcounter{num}
    \noindent
    \only#2{\begin{mdframed}[style=QueFrame]    
        \hbox{          
        {\color{blue}\transparent{0.3}\Huge Q{\huge\thenum}} --- #1}
    \end{mdframed}}
}

\newcommand<>\Ans[2][]{
    \leavevmode\par
    \noindent
    \begin{flushright}
        \only#3{\begin{mdframed}[style=AnsFrame]
            \textbf{#1} #2  --- {\Huge\color{blue}\transparent{0.3} A}
        \end{mdframed}}
    \end{flushright}
}
```

allows to use:

```
\begin{frame}
    \Que<1->{What is \LaTeX{}?}
    \Ans<2->{\LaTeX{} is a document preparation system and document markup language!}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \Que<1->{Why I should use \LaTeX?}
    \Ans<2->{\LaTeX{} provides very high quality. \LaTeX{} is free and Open Source!}
\end{frame}
```

The complete example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\setbeamercovered{transparent=0}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=lime!20}

\usepackage{transparent}

\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\mdfdefinestyle{QueFrame}{%
    linecolor       = blue!30,
    outerlinewidth      = 2pt,
    roundcorner     = 10pt,
    leftmargin      = 10pt,
    rightmargin     = 80pt,
    innertopmargin      = \baselineskip,
    innerbottommargin   = \baselineskip,
    innerrightmargin    = 20pt,
    innerleftmargin     = 20pt,
    backgroundcolor     = red!20!white
}

\mdfdefinestyle{AnsFrame}{
    linecolor       = red!30,
    outerlinewidth      = 2pt,
    roundcorner     = 10pt,
    leftmargin      = 80pt,
    rightmargin     = 10pt,
    innertopmargin      = \baselineskip,
    innerbottommargin   = \baselineskip,
    innerrightmargin    = 20pt,
    innerleftmargin     = 20pt,
    backgroundcolor     = blue!20!white
}

\newcounter{num}
\setcounter{num}{0}

\newcommand<>\Que[1]{
    \leavevmode\par
    \stepcounter{num}
    \noindent
    \only#2{\begin{mdframed}[style=QueFrame]    
        \hbox{          
        {\color{blue}\transparent{0.3}\Huge Q{\huge\thenum}} --- #1}
    \end{mdframed}}
}

\newcommand<>\Ans[2][]{
    \leavevmode\par
    \noindent
    \begin{flushright}
        \only#3{\begin{mdframed}[style=AnsFrame]
            \textbf{#1} #2  --- {\Huge\color{blue}\transparent{0.3} A}
        \end{mdframed}}
    \end{flushright}
}

\resetcounteronoverlays{num}

\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}

\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=green!20}

\begin{frame}
    \Que<1->{What is \LaTeX{}?}
    \Ans<2->{\LaTeX{} is a document preparation system and document markup language!}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \Que<1->{Why I should use \LaTeX?}
    \Ans<2->{\LaTeX{} provides very high quality. \LaTeX{} is free and Open Source!}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: It also ran well, @Claudio Fiandrino.

Answer (score 4):

Based on [Gonzalo Medina](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3954/gonzalo-medina) answers, I did some adjustments:

**Title**

```
\usebeamerfont{title}
%\inserttitle\par % disabled
\begin{mdframed}[style=QueFrame]
    \inserttitle{\huge\color{blue} Questions and Answer}
\end{mdframed}
```

**Author**

```
\usebeamerfont{author}
    %\insertauthor % disabled
\begin{mdframed}[style=AnsFrame]
    \insertauthor{\Large\color{blue} Edy Wihardjo}
\end{mdframed}
```

and

```
%\title{The title} % disabled
%\author{The Author} % disabled
```

This is what I want

**Before**

[image: Title Page Before]

**After**

[image: Title Page After]